# Loading Specific Views

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a bit new to iOS Development as a whole. I'm trying to create a Journal Application, but struggling with something many of you might understand more than me. I am trying to load a specific view based on an argument. In my case, on the Applications first load, I want to load the "Setup" view as the default page. But after the first load (aka after the user has setup their profile or whatever), I want to load the "Master" view (the page which displays the necessary info such as creation of a new journal entry and such)

Currently I have this code inside of my viewDidLoad:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if userDefaults.value(forKey: "firstTimeLoad") as? Bool != nil {
// FIXME: Add code which loads the setup view

            userDefaults.setValue(true, forKey: "firstTimeLoad")
            userDefaults.synchronize()
        } else if userDefaults.value(forKey: "firstTimeLoad") as? Bool == nil {
// FIXME: Add code which hides the Setup view and loads the Master view.
        }
    }
```

I've tried a few things such as loading a specific view with loadView, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I would say it would be easier to accomplish this using different `UIViewControllers` instead of `UIViews`

Answer (score 0):

Ah, you should do this via AppDelegate.swift

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    //If you have key, push your master view.
    if userDefaults.value(forKey: "firstTimeLoad") as? Bool != nil {
        return loadMasterViewController()
    } else {
        userDefaults.setValue(true, forKey: "firstTimeLoad")
        userDefaults.synchronize()
    }
    return true
}

func loadMasterViewController() -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let masterViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MasterViewController")
    self.window?.rootViewController = masterViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to do:

The result:

[image]

In your VC1:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        userDefaults.setValue(false, forKey: "firstTimeLoad")  // you can set firstTimeLoad's value for vc2 to load different view.
        userDefaults.synchronize()
    }

}
```

In your VC2:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

var view1:UIView?
var view2:UIView?

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    view1 = UIView.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    view1?.backgroundColor = .red
    view2 = UIView.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    view2?.backgroundColor = .blue


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if userDefaults.value(forKey: "firstTimeLoad") as? Bool == false {
        // FIXME: Add code which loads the setup view

        self.view.addSubview(view1!)


        userDefaults.setValue(true, forKey: "firstTimeLoad")  // attention: there I changed the firstTimeLoad value to true, so next time you run in vc1, will load the blue view.
        userDefaults.synchronize()
    } else if userDefaults.value(forKey: "firstTimeLoad") as? Bool == true {
        // FIXME: Add code which hides the Setup view and loads the Master view.

        self.view.addSubview(view2!)
    }
}
}
```